# Why is the scroll view being nil?

Tags: swift, xcode, null, uiscrollview

I have the following code:

```
extension SegmentedControlViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // this checks for whether contentOffset.x is around 10 (contented shifted to the right by 10 points)
        if abs(scrollView.contentOffset.x - 10) < 1 {
            print("works")
        }
    }
}
```

```
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

then I call the function in the viewDidLoad like this:

```
scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
```

Although I am always getting the error message

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong, how to  Get the scroll view to not be nil.

Comment: Either you haven't connected `@IBOutlet` or your code is called before `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @user28434 I was just reviewing that and it didn't help me

Comment: @user28434 also I have my outlet connected and I call the function in the viewDidLoad

Comment: You're probably asking the wrong question. `scrollViewDidScroll()` is a delegate function, called by UIKit when the scroll view has scrolled. What are you trying to accomplish by calling it directly from `viewDidLoad()` (where it has not yet been setup by auto layout and cannot possibly have scrolled)?

Comment: @DonMag where should I call it then?

Comment: @coder123 - ***"What are you trying to accomplish by calling it?"***

Comment: @DonMag all I am trying to accomplish printing "works" to the console when the content offset is more than 10

Comment: @coder123 - then assign the delegate of your scroll view, and start scrolling.

Comment: @DonMag I'm sort of new to coding what do you mean by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the scroll view's `.delegate` in `viewDidLoad()` and start scrolling:

```
class SegmentedControlViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // assign the delegate      
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }

}

extension SegmentedControlViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // this checks for whether contentOffset.x is around 10 (contented shifted to the right by 10 points)
        if abs(scrollView.contentOffset.x - 10) < 1 {
            print("works")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to check if the scroll view content has been dragged to the right more than 10 points, use this:

```
extension SegmentedControlViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // this checks for whether contentOffset.x is around 10 (contented shifted to the right by 10 points)
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x < 10 {
            print("scroll content has been dragged to the right more than 10 points")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you putting the time in to help me out with this, thanks.